# pgfplots - disable smoothness

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using following pgfplots to draw a simple function:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-4:4,
    xscale=2.25,yscale=1.125,
    xmin=-4, xmax=4,
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    samples=500,
    axis lines=center,
    grid=both,
    xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
]
    \addplot+[orange,mark=none,very thick] {rad(asin((2*x)/((x^2)+1)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
```

It renders this plot:

[image: Plot with wrong smoothness]

As you see, the spikes are curved, although I have not used the "smooth" option in \addplot.

Does anyone know, if there is a way to make the spikes sharper?

(Sorry for my English.)

Comment: If you write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` (or newer) into your preamble and compile the example with `lualatex`, it will also be fine. This makes use of the `lua backend` and has higher accuracy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is determine enough large number of samples so, that will one lie at each spike. Then the obtained image is:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-4:4,
    xscale=2.25,yscale=1.125,
    xmin=-4, xmax=4,
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    samples=150,
    axis lines=center,
    grid=both,
    xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
]
    \addplot[orange,very thick,mark=none] {rad(asin((2*x)/((x^2)+1)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, in waran's code, more samples are used (500 instead of 150). I think this might have something to do with the approximations PGF uses for trigonometric functions. In this case, more samples actually leads to worse results.

Comment: I observe similarly. Number of samples over 150 gives me worse result. And number should be even.

Comment: I wonder if `samples at` could be chosen to give good results...

Comment: @cmhughes, yes, this seems to be one option, however, manually set adequate number of samples  fast become challenging.

Comment: `samples at={-4,-3.9,...,-1,-0.99,-0.9,...,1,1.01,1.1,...,4}` works pretty well and is only slightly tedious.

Comment: Setting the samples to 150 worked for me, altough it might not be the most elegant method. :) Thanks.